# How to passing the pointer parameters and return them right?

Tags: c, parameter-passing

Here is my code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void foo(int size, int new_size, int * ptr1, double * ptr2) {
    int i;
    new_size = size * 2;
    ptr1 = (int *) calloc(new_size, sizeof(int));
    ptr2 = (double *) calloc(new_size, sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
        ptr1[i] = 1;
        ptr2[i] = 2;
    }
}
int main(){
    int i, size = 4, new_size = 4;
    int *ptr1 = NULL;
    double *ptr2 = NULL;

    foo(size, new_size, ptr1, ptr2);

    for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
        printf("new_size: %d\n", new_size);
        printf("ptr1: %d, ptr2: %f\n", ptr1[i], ptr2[i]);
    }

    free(ptr1);
    free(ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

And I have to malloc space and assign data to ptr1 and ptr2 in foo function (because I don't know the new size of them in main functin) and then use them in the main function.
**Why the code doesn't work? And How to implement the above process I want?**

Comment: `new_size = size * 2;` this seems weird though why have `new_size` as function parameter if you don't use its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the addresses of the pointers, modify the pointers in the functions and thats all, other that that I have a few observations on your code

1. Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, it's not necessary in c, and it [hurts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495) your code readability.
2. Always check the return value of `malloc()` and pretty much any function that returns a value, because normally there is a special value indicating failure, and you don't want your program to misbehave under extraordinary conditions.

This is a version of your own code with the main issue addressed and also the observations above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(int size, int new_size, int ** ptr1, double ** ptr2) {
    int        i;
    new_size = size * 2;

    *ptr1 = malloc(new_size * sizeof(int));
    *ptr2 = NULL;
    if (*ptr1 == NULL)
        return 1;

    *ptr2 = malloc(new_size * sizeof(double));
    if (*ptr2 == NULL) {
         free(*ptr1); 
         return 2;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
        (*ptr1)[i] = 1;
        (*ptr2)[i] = 2;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int i, size = 4, new_size = 4;
    int    *ptr1 = NULL;
    double *ptr2 = NULL;

    if (foo(size, new_size, &ptr1, &ptr2) != 0)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
        printf("new_size: %d\n", new_size);
        printf("ptr1: %d, ptr2: %f\n", ptr1[i], ptr2[i]);
    }

    free(ptr1);
    free(ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

In c you always pass parameters by value, it might be confusing because you are passing a pointer, but a pointer is just another variable which stores a memory address, that address is changing inside the `foo()` function but it's only being written into the local pointer `ptr1`.

Passing the address writes the value to the original pointer in `main()`.

Comment: Your malloc won't give the right size since sizeof(ptr1) is the size of a pointer.

Comment: Oops I didn't type the `*`.

Comment: Now I thought it could be confusing for the OP to do `malloc(new_size * sizeof(**ptr1))`... so this could be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the address of the pointer to the function like so:

```
void foo(int size, int new_size, int ** ptr1, double ** ptr2) {
    int i;
    new_size = size * 2;
    *ptr1 = (int *) calloc(new_size, sizeof(int));
    *ptr2 = (double *) calloc(new_size, sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
        (*ptr1)[i] = 1;
        (*ptr2)[i] = 2;
    }
}
```

and in main

```
foo(size, new_size, &ptr1, &ptr2);
```

Your code didn't work because parameter are passed by value. `ptr1` and `ptr2` while being pointers are still passed by values so any modification to them(compared to modification to what they point to) will not remain after the function.

Comment: You noticed the problem with your code `*ptr[i] != (*ptr)[i]`.

Comment: @iharob Yes I was typing a bit too fast. You noticed yours with the malloc ? Thanks